# Android automotive | Enable automotive

Tags: android, android-automotive, automotive, aaos

I'm trying to create my own android automotive emulator. The build was successful and working.

The issue is that : my emulator is a car emulator, but I don't get the car data information in the extended controls of the emulator.

[image]

I'm missing : car data, sensor replay, car rotary

in the makefile I used :

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-service \

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.type.automotive.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/permissions/android.hardware.type.automotive.xml \

Comment: Which build target you used? It's sdk_car_(abi)?

Answer (score 0):

If I launch the latest green build of `sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug` on Linux by following [Launch an AOSP Car AVD using prebuilt](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/avd/android_virtual_device#launch-an-aosp-car-avd-using-prebuilt), I can see Car data relevant emulator menus. Could you please try it by yourself?

I used build id 11494777 on [aosp-main-throttled](https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-main-throttled/grid?legacy=1) branch.

Comment: thanks, I was able to use sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug as base for my device. and it is  working thanks